# n largest values declustered

Tags: r, max

Consider a dataframe with a time column in seconds and a value column x.
I am trying to find the indexes of the n largest values of x that are separated by a time of at least lambda from one another.

As an example if df is the following:

```
time, x

1, 100
2, 95
4, 10
5, 100
7, 99
8, 98
10, 98
12, 10
```

Looking for the 3 largest values separated by 4 seconds, `nlargest(data = df, n = 3, lambda = 4)` should return 1, 5, 10.

I have not found a smart way to do this unfortunately. Any hint would be very welcome!

Comment: What do you mean "3 largest values separated by 4 seconds"? The set of 3 values separated by >= 4 seconds whose sum is larger than any other such set?

Comment: Maybe the full picture will help. I am looking at extreme events, but they are clustered. Instead of detecting the 3 largest elements without regards to if they are grouped or not (which would yield 1, 5, 7 in this case), I am hoping to remove the values close in time from the set under consideration (then yielding 1, 5, 10, because 7 is within 4 seconds of 5 while 10 is not). I hope it is clearer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `time != 1:k` (or if `time == 1:k`) you can do

```
set.seed(94)
df     <- data.frame(time  = seq(1,200,2), x = sample(1:200))
n      <- 4
lambda <- 20

sorted <- df[order(-df$x),]
result <- sorted[1,]

i <- 1
while (nrow(result) < n){
    if (all(abs(sorted[i, 'time'] - result[, 'time']) >= lambda)) {
        result <- rbind(result, sorted[i,])
    }
    i <- i + 1
}

result[,2]
## [1] 200 199 198 196

min(abs(diff(result[order(result$time),'time']))) >= lambda
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan. Although this solution appears to take longer, it is more general.

Comment: I've changed the `for` loop to a `while` loop since it's unnecessary to keep looping after you get `n` values. Should be faster now.

Comment: My solution gives different result because I use `>` and you  `>=`. Change this and both works the same for this data.

Comment: Actually I am not sure what your solution does. The maxima are still grouped even when the bandwidth is large.

Comment: @bartektartanus Bad example. Fixed

Comment: Sorry is there a way I can make this prettier?
@Ryan 
`set.seed(994)
df     <- data.frame(time  = sort(sample(1:600)[1:200]), x = sample(1:200))
n      <- 10
lambda <- 20

sorted <- df[order(-df$x),]
result <- sorted[1,]

i <- 1
while (nrow(result) < n){
  if (abs(sorted[i, 'time'] - result[nrow(result), 'time']) >= lambda) {
    result <- rbind(result, sorted[i,])
  }
  i <- i + 1
}

result <- result[order(result$time),]
min(diff(result$time))
===> 8`

Comment: @RobertSilverman Oops, you're right. I was only checking distance from last result. Should be fixed now (added `all`).

Answer (score 1):

You can order the values and then check if indexes are far enough from each other using `diff` function.

```
set.seed(42) 
lambda <- 4
n <- 3
df <- data.frame(time=1:20,x=sample(1:100,20))
df
#   time  x
#   1     1 92
#   2     2 93
#   3     3 29
#   4     4 81
#   5     5 62
#   6     6 50
#   7     7 70
#   8     8 13
#   9     9 61
#   10   10 65
#   11   11 42
#   12   12 91
#   13   13 83
#   14   14 23
#   15   15 40
#   16   16 80
#   17   17 88
#   18   18 10
#   19   19 39
#   20   20 46
o <- order(df$x,decreasing = TRUE) # get the order of values
# select values which indexes are far enough 
df$x[o[c(TRUE,abs(diff(df$time[o]))>lambda)]][1:n] 
# [1] 93 91 88
sort(df$x,dec=TRUE)[1:3]
# [1] 93 92 91
```

As you can see, using just `sort` function returns 93 (which is second) followed by 92 (which is first) == too close.

Comment: This works! Unless time != 1:k. Thank you bartektartanus.

Comment: Replaced `diff(o)` with `diff(df$time[o])` but I guess it's still incomplete and I'm not sure if this can be done without for/while loop.